# Pattern match Erlang string as list in function

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have recently started to study Erlang and have encountered a curious exception which I cannot explain.

My source code is as follows:

```
-module(balanced_brackets).                                                                                                              
-author("Irrelevant").
-compile(export_all).

is_balanced(String) -> is_balanced(String, 0, 0).

is_balanced([H | T], Opening, Closing) when H =:= "{" ->
    is_balanced(T, Opening + 1, Closing);
is_balanced([H | T], Opening, Closing) when H =:= "}" ->
    is_balanced(T, Opening, Closing + 1);
is_balanced([], Opening, Closing) -> (Opening - Closing).
```

Very basic code to count the number of closing and opening curly brackets in a string.

In the Erlang shell, when I try to call the function is_balanced as such:
`balanced_brackets:is_balanced("{}").`

The following error is output:

`** exception error: no function clause matching balanced_brackets:is_balanced("{}",0,0) (balanced_brackets.erl, line 7)`

However, if I pass the argument as an explicit list, pattern matching works correctly:
`balanced_brackets:is_balanced(["{", "}"]).`

Aren't Erlang strings simply lists internally? Why is it incorrect to pattern match a string using the construct `[H | T]`?

Executing the BIF `is_list("{}").` returns `true`.

I would sincerely appreciate somebody's explanation for the exception.

Thank you.

`Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2] [source-aaaefb3] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your guard definition, you are comparing to `"{"` which is `[123]`, i.e. a list with one element representing `{`.

Your pattern matching is correct, but you will want to match against `123` instead of `"{"` (and the same for `}` of course).

The easiest way to fix your code (and keep it readable) is to compare to `[H]` instead of `H` in the guards:

```
is_balanced([H | T], Opening, Closing) when [H] =:= "{" ->
    is_balanced(T, Opening + 1, Closing);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you for the concise explanation. Marking as accepted.

Comment: or you can compare H to ${, another way to represent 123, but showing it as a character.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use numbers to represent characters as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581636/pattern-match-erlang-string-as-list-in-function/27581746#27581746). Rather, just use Erlang character constants. For example, to represent the `{` character, you'd use `${`.

A good way to fix the code is to avoid the guards entirely and just match `${` and `$}` characters in the function heads, like this:

```
is_balanced([${ | T], Opening, Closing) ->
    is_balanced(T, Opening + 1, Closing);
is_balanced([$} | T], Opening, Closing) ->
    is_balanced(T, Opening, Closing + 1);
```

You then need another clause to handle characters other than `${` and `$}`, which is missing from the original code:

```
is_balanced([_ | T], Opening, Closing) ->
    is_balanced(T, Opening, Closing);
```

And finally, keep the original final clause to handle the empty list, ending the recursion:

```
is_balanced([], Opening, Closing) -> (Opening - Closing).
```

One more thing: given the function name `is_balanced`, it would seem to want to return a boolean. If so, change the top function to this:

```
is_balanced(String) -> is_balanced(String, 0, 0) == 0.
```